# Jacoco analyzed bundle '...' with 0 classes when used with Cucumber

Tags: maven, cucumber, jacoco

I am currently working on Jacoco code coverage for a Maven project with Cucumber integration tests.
My pom.xml file has jacoco and failsafe plugins as shown in the pictures, with reference from https://github.com/dimazelinskyi/jacoco-coverage-cucumber-unit-tests.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco-reports/jacoco-test.exec</destFile>
                <propertyName>failsafeJacocoAgent</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco-reports/jacoco-test.exec</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco-reports/jacoco-test</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${failsafeJacocoAgent}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>junit-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <testNGArtifactName>none:none</testNGArtifactName>
                <argLine>${failsafeJacocoAgent}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>testng-integration-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${failsafeJacocoAgent}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/CukeRunnerTest.java</include>
        </includes>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <isMavenTest>true</isMavenTest>
            <client.uri>${wipdm.app.base.url}</client.uri>
            <cucumber.options>${async.option}</cucumber.options>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
        <properties>
            <async.option>--tags ~@longRunningTest</async.option>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And the CukeRunnerTest.java file looks like this: [CukeRunnerTest.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOF0x.png)

When I build with maven i.e. mvn clean install, all tests successfully pass, however I get a message saying

```
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\Users\...\IdeaProjects\...\target\jacoco-reports\jacoco-test.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'wipdata-war' with 0 classes
```

The build is successful and jacoco-it.exec file is generated, but no reports are generated.

Is this expected behaviour? As I thought that jacoco would check the Cucumber feature files inside "src/test/features/v3" (which is stated inside CukeRunnerTest.java) to see which code in the java files they covered in their integration tests.

Any advice or help is much appreciated.

Comment: try to change the goal from verify to install in maven-failsafe-plugin

Comment: Hi, it seems that maven-failsafe-plugin does not allow a goal of install, as I tried it and got an error ````Could not find goal 'install' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.12 among available goals integration-test, verify, help````